# Passport string regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement regex validation for passport number.

1. Length: 5-20 char Alphanumeric
2. Allowed characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 (case insensitive)
3. Cannot contain only 1 digit or character, repeated

Example: (what I expect to see)

```
11111111 - false // "1" is repeated
111112 - true // string contains "2"
fdgADGF12 - true
AAAAAAAAAAA - false
bbbbbbb - false
```

My regex:

```
/^(.){2,}[A-Za-z0-9]{5,20}$/
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Try: `/^(?!(.)\1+$)[A-Za-z0-9]{5,20}$/`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:-

```
^(?!^0+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,9}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
^(?!(.)\1+$)[A-Za-z\d]{5,20}$
```